# Bootstrap 4 how to evenly spread the button around (and vertical aligned)?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using the following code to generate the buttons below, but 1) the button couldn't spread across the, after using `btn-block` suggested. And also the button didn't center-aligned, as `justify-content-center` suggested. I pasted my code below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col pl-1">
            <div class="form-row no-gutters h-100">
                <div class="form-group col card form-header text-center">
                    <div class="card-header form-label">
                        <label for="action">Action <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body h-100 d-flex flex-column">
                        <div class="p-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-block" id="refresh"><i
                                class="fas fa-sync"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-block" id="selectAll"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-block" id="deselectAll" disabled><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block" id="call" disabled>C</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-block" id="put" disabled>P</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the screenshow below:

[image]

I would like to 1) Vertical Align the button 2) Decrease the spacing between the buttons 3) Make sure the whole `card` align with the box on the left (I used `h-100` to ensure it fills the whole height). Similar to the pics below:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tell me that what you want to achieve

Comment: please provide the exact environment to reproduce your situation and explain further what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for missing some information. I added some comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply edit one class of bootstrap `.col-1` to `.col-4` and you get the like image

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-4 pl-1">
  <div class="form-row no-gutters h-100">
    <div class="form-group col card form-header text-center">
      <div class="card-header form-label">
        <label for="action">Action <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></label>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="p-2">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-block" id="refresh"><i
                                class="fas fa-sync"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-block" id="selectAll"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary btn-block" id="deselectAll" disabled><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block" id="call" disabled>C</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-block" id="put" disabled>P</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually the form on the left uses a lot of spaces so I have no choice but give col-1. In addition do you know how can I get the buttons 'fatter'?

Comment: Also I would like to vertical center the buttons. It doesn't work ATM. Please check my updated code snippet above.

Comment: Please you can provide the exact screen shot of what ever you want